# java while loop is not counting correctly

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

Imma java newbie so I try to learn things. I created a boolean method, it's a small craps game. I need this method is called from main method and keep playing while return value is true (game is won) but stop executing if return value is false. I also need how many times player won. So I created something like this:

```
while(Craps.play())
{
  Craps.play();
  i++;
} 

System.out.println("In total you won " + i + " times");
```

`i` is initialized as private static int `i = 0; //Game counter`

But output didn't see me correct. First of all, if the game is lost (return value is false) it wo't stop execution. And it doesn't count winning number correct. For example if 3 games are won, it calculates if he won 2 games.

Is there any logic error with this loop?

Thanks

Comment: Calling `Craps.play();` in the while condition *and* in the body may be the problem.

Comment: The problem may be that you call the `Craps#play` function inside the `while-loop` two times: one as a condition, another inside the `while` block code

Comment: Yep just remove the "Craps.play()" call in the *while* loop body

Comment: Could you post the code for Craps.play() so that we can see exactly what it does and what it is?

Comment: what is wrong with `while(Craps.play()){i++; //other logic...}` ?

Comment: I would create a public method to get the play state, ie Craps.isPlaying() which can return the flag.  Calling play() twice is probably not what you want.

Comment: To further your refactor, why would you need an outer counter?  I would advocate for keeping all that information internal to Carps instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `Craps.play()` inside the loop, since you will miss validations. Also, in your original code, you are calling `Craps.play()` twice, but you are incremeting `i` only once. Change your code to this and it should work as expected:

```
 while(Craps.play()) {
     i++;
 }
```

Comment: Oh yes. I made this change, and now the code is working correctly. Thanks guys for your prompt answers.